# Button Image Not Seen in BoxLayout

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import json

class MainInterface(BoxLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainInterface()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

KV:

```
MainInterface:
<MainInterface>:
    ScreenManager:
        id: sm
        size: root.width, root.height
        Screen:
            name: 'homepage_screen'
            Image:
                source: 'C:\\Users\\Messi\\Desktop\\Python\\Projects\\Football Tips\\Kivy\\images\\homepage_background.png'
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: False
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint: 1, 0.10
                Button: 
                    background_color: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1                   
                    Image:
                        source: 'images\\button1.png'  
                        size: self.parent.size
                        allow_stretch: True
                Button:
                    background_color: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1  
                    Image:
                        source: 'images\\button2.png'
                        size: self.parent.size
                        allow_stretch: True
```

[image]

Although there is a boxlayout inside screen, i can see only one Button Image. There are two button but one Image is missing and it shows me the last button Image (images\button2.png) that i add!
Could you please help me to fix it.
I want to see all Imaged Buttons that i add.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Images` that are inside your `Buttons` do not have positions assigned, so they both get the default `(0,0)` and one obscures the other. You can fix that by either assigning positions by adding:

```
                    pos: self.parent.pos
```

to each of those `Images`. Or you could just define a custom `Image` that uses `ButtonBehavior` and use that in plcae of your `Button/Image` combination.. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.button.html#example).